# U1256 LONDN TO BESCOT STADIUM

Tags: trains

I have received a train ticket stipulating From U1256 LONDN to BESCOT STADIUM.
Can you confirm this covers my underground travel from Heathrow through to London Euston and then my onward travel through to Bescot, Walsall?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this should be fine. `U1256` really means "a connecting underground journey in zones 1-6", including 3 and 4, except it has been shortened to fit in the space on the ticket -- this is also the reason for the missing O in `LONDN`.

Heathrow is in zone 6.

Beware that your ticket will not be valid on the TfL Rail or Heathrow Express trains to Paddington; you'll need to take the Piccadilly Line (and then probably walk from King's Cross St Pancras underground station; changing train to reach Euston by tube will be slower).